# Importing .json data using SCANOVER and character string input

Tags: json, sas

This is a preview of my .json file:

```
{
  "hash": "d1373fa42e50dac98",
  "hash_type": "tba",
  "id": "bac8c65c6d50a4fbf129",
  "delivered_at": "tba0",
  "interactions": [
    {
      "demographic": {
        "gender": "tba"
      },
      "interaction": {
        "schema": {
          "version": 3
        },
        "source": "tba",
        "author": {
          "username": "tba",
          "name": "tba",
          "id": tba,
          "avatar": "tbag",
          "link": "tba",
          "language": "en"
        },
        "type": "tba",
        "created_at": "Wed, 12 Mar 2014 18:48:03 +0000",
        "received_at": 1394650083.9589,
        "content": "\"tba" Dummy text. #tba  http://t.co/tba",
        "id": "1e3aa16d7563a380",
        "link": "tba",
        "hashtags": [
          "tbaa"
        ]
      },
```

I would like to import it to SAS. For example import the information regarding the two "id" values (you will find it at the beginning of the preview and at the end). I have used this code:

```
filename data 'Test\test.json';  
data datatest; 
infile data lrecl = 32000 truncover scanover; 
input @'"id":"' id $300.  ; 
id = substr(id,1,index(id,'",')-1); 
run;
```

Unfortunately this results in an output only containing the first "id" value (bac8c65c6d50a4fbf129) but not the second one (1e3aa16d7563a380). How come?

Comment: Are you reading in a Twitter feed?

Comment: not sure where the file is from... it was sent to me from a friend - i am just doing the technical part :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have inconsistent spacing, I'd guess.  This works with your example, although your initial example probably shouldn't work at all.

```
data test;
infile "d:\temp\jsontest.txt" scanover truncover lrecl=32767;
input @'"id":' id $300.;
id=scan(id,1,'",');
run;
```

Get rid of the third quote [the opening quote on the text item] - so you capture the entire quoted string - and then you can deal with that easily.  In this case, `scan` with " and , delimiters removes them nicely (technically it's taking the first 'word' with those delimiters).  You also could use `dequote` to remove them if you take out the comma (either with scan, or using , as a delimiter on the file, or somethign else).

If you're parsing twitter, or something like it, there are some good explanations of how to do this.  [This blog post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sascom/2013/12/12/how-to-import-twitter-tweets-in-sas-data-step-using-oauth-2-authentication-style/) for example shows how to use OAuth2, but also shows you how to use `PROC GROOVY` to use a proper JSON parser to read the JSON rather than having to roll your own parser (as you are above).  If you're familiar with Groovy, it's pretty easy to incorporate into SAS if you have 9.3+.

Comment: I will check on the source and then look up groovy.

`data datatest; 
infile data lrecl = 32000 truncover scanover; 
input @'"id":' id $300.; 
id=scan(id,1,'",'); 
run;` 

Unfortunately the changes still result in only one entry. Maybe the actual file helps: http://we.tl/AEy4Hsd3UK

Comment: Cool... it works with the code you provided. Not sure why I had trouble with it before. One question regarding the delimeter - how do I have to adjust the code so that it searches till the expression "," (the quotation marks left and right and the comma in the middle together mark the delimeter).

Comment: You could use a DLMSTR (in 9.2+) on the INFILE statement.  (DLM='","' would take any of the chars, DLMSTR='","' would require all 3)